# allowing regular expression search in mongodb with encoded url query parameters

Tags: angularjs, regex, node.js, mongodb, search

I have a angular-fullstack app generated from angular-fullstack yeoman generator and I am sending the search text with the url as a query parameter
That's why it is getting encoded like this -

```
http://localhost:9000/api/query?limit=5&searchText=sample+question+title+%5B
```

`[` got encoded to `%5B`

Now in my server side controller I am doing -

```
var escapeRegExpChars = function (text) {
        return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    };
if(req.query.searchText != undefined && req.query.searchText != '')
        queryObj['title']= new RegExp(escapeRegExpChars(req.query.searchText), 'i');

var query = Query.find(queryObj).exec(function(err,queries){});
```

So, how do I enable regular expression search on my client side ?

Comment: You don't need anything. If you `console.log(req.query.searchText)` you will see it is url decoded and shows "sample question title ["

Comment: but then the results are not displayed if I enter a regular expression in client side input text box

Comment: also if I enter `/sample/i` in client side it and do a `console.log(queryObj)` I get `{ title: /\/sample\/i\ q/i }` is this correct ?